# Why does true variant booleans become -1 when cast to an integer?

Tags: delphi

I realise that one should not expect true `Boolean`s to become `1` when cast to an `Integer`, purely that they become non-`0`.

However, the result changes depending on whether the variable is a `Variant` (but `varBoolean`) or a `Boolean`.

Consider the following:

```
I := Integer(true);
```

`I` is now `1`.

But...

```
var
  I: Integer;
  V: Variant;
begin
  V := true;
  I := Integer(V);
end;
```

`I` is now `-1`.

Of course, if I cast V to a `Boolean` before casting the resulting `Boolean` to an `Integer`, `I` becomes `-1`.

But I am curious as to why that is.

Is this because of the way that `Boolean`s are stored (say as `1` bits), and when casting to an `Integer`, Delphi performs a conversion, which does not occur when casting a `Variant` to `Integer`?

I only bring this up, because if you are used to a true `Boolean` casting to `1`, it can be dangerous to have `varBoolean` share case with `varInteger` in a `VarType()`-`case`.

For instance:

```
case VarType(V) of 
  varInteger, varBoolean: I := Integer(V);
end;
```

Would not behave as one might expect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The behaviour is indeed as expected. The `varBoolean` type corresponds to `VT_BOOL`. Which is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221170.aspx) like this:

> **VT_BOOL**
>
> A Boolean value. True is -1 and false is 0.

You also say that Delphi's boolean is stored as 1 bit. That's not actually true. They are stored in a single byte, 8 bits. I suppose the key point is that a `VT_BOOL` variant does not contain a Delphi `Boolean`. The `VT_BOOL` variant is a different beast altogether, dating originally from VB. Raymond Chen discusses this a little here: [BOOL vs. VARIANT_BOOL vs. BOOLEAN vs. bool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx).

Comment: Also, [OLE Automation Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc237864.aspx) states that `VARIANT_BOOL` may contain either `VARIANT_TRUE` (`$FFFF`) or `VARIANT_FALSE` (`$0000`).

Comment: I might not have been clear, but I meant that Delphi's `Boolean` type is stored as a series of 1 bit*s*.  I assume the 8 bits are all 1 when the boolean is true.

Comment: That's not what happens. Delphi's `Boolean` is an 8 bit value, a byte. When you write `b := False`, `b` is set to `0`. When you write `b := True`, `b` is set to `1`. In binary that is `00000001`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I thought I would add the slight inconsistency in that the SysUtils.BoolToStr() function, by default, returns '-1' as true and '0' as false.

And to confuse things a little more SysUtils.StrToBool() returns true if the string is any number (even a float) not 0.