# Why delphi BoolToStr true is represented as -1

Tags: delphi, boolean, pascal

Delphi function [BoolToStr](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.BoolToStr) converts boolean value to a string.

The result is either true or false, or 'numeric', '-1' and '0' respectively. Why -1 and not 1?

Comment: See also [Why does true variant booleans become -1 when cast to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31828307/576719)

Comment: Declared in the windows unit is `type Bool = System.LongBool`, and `Ord(Bool(TRUE))` is `-1`.

Comment: Just for fun: `Boolean(42)` evaluates to true. `Boolean(42) and true` evaluates to true, but `Boolean(42) = true` evaluates to false. Perhaps there is some logic behind that, but it would more be like [fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic).

Comment: @LURD - Same thing as I commented to Golez's answer. "=" is not a boolean operator so the compiler have to compare binary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The source of these particular values is surely down to the `0` and `-1` being the values used by the COM boolean type.

Certainly in older versions of the Delphi RTL this function was used when converting variants from one type to another, so I'd be reasonable confident that COM variant support was the reason behind this decision.

You can see the remnants of that original code today in `VariantChangeSimpleIntoSimple` found in `System.VarUtils`. When asked to convert `varBoolean` to `varOleStr` it does:

```
VarOleStrFromStr(Dest, BoolToStr(LSource.VBoolean))
```

Further reading:

- [BOOL vs. VARIANT_BOOL vs. BOOLEAN vs. bool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041222-00/?p=36923).
- [Not Logical Is VBScript](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/07/15/not-logical-is-vbscript/)

Comment: I guess that answers why Delphi does it so, any knowledge why the 'Visual Basic folks' ended up with that design?

Comment: I'd also bet on COM compatibility. Note that the definition can be adapted using true/falseboolstrs.

Comment: @Doege: my recollection about the early days of COM is a bit vague, but it would not surprise me if COM got this and some others things from early VB, and not the other way around. But anyway, VB and COM were always tightly coupled, especially in the days when VB was not .NET yet.

Answer (score 10):

A possible explanation is that a boolean is typically not stored in a single bit, but in an integer. If you do a bitwise `not` of an integer 0 (binary 0000 0000 ...), it will be binary 1111 1111 ....), which means -1 for two complements signed integers.

So if you say, `false := 0; true := not false;`, it makes sense that true is -1.

In the various BASIC dialect, true is also -1 for the same reason.

Comment: The same convention is used in many languages and on many devices including microcontrollers, and for the same reason. If you use unsigned rather than signed convention the value would depend on the number of bytes used to store the value, but with the signed convention it is always -1

Comment: Ord(Boolean(True)) is 1 and a boolean is the size of a byte.

Comment: In Delphi there are also other boolean types, mainly for compatibility with other languages and OS'es. `ByteBool,WordBool,LongBool` where the binary value of Ord(xxxxBool(True)) is (1111 1111 ...). See [System.ByteBool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ByteBool).

Comment: @LURD: in Delphi. But not in many other languages. GolezTrol is right that often, *true = not false* (and *not 0* is *-1*). Heck, in C, often any non-zero value is considered to be true.

Comment: @Rudy Not often, always

Comment: Indeed. Many Windows API's return a boolean (or 'longbool') value, where the documentation says things like `non-zero` rather than 'true' or even 1 or -1.

Comment: .. Even for Delphi that's the case. Which cause some confusion among novice; when "if B" branches to the "if" but "if B = true" branches to "else".

Comment: @David: I meant in the bitwise sense, not in the logical one. In Delphi, *not False = True*, but *(not 0) = -1*. In the bitwise sense, *not False* would be *Boolean(255)* (and *not True* would be *Boolean(254)*).

Comment: @rudy you said "in C, often any non-zero value is considered to be true". Non zero value is always considered to be true.

Comment: @David: that is very often, indeed. <g>

Comment: If this was the reason, it would surely effect binary storage and not only textual representation. See LURD's first comment.

Comment: Lazarus had fun with this with the early glib/gtk2 headers. Their boolean type is like pascal's, but then 32-bit.  Using longbool makes true -1, but gtk2 internally checks against true=1, so the passed booleans were never true. So now FPC has boolean16,boolean32,boolean64 (and the old boolean is boolean8)

Comment: After this answer we actually had an issue with a failing unit test, where it turned out that two booleans had different non-zero values. The comparison thought they were not equal, but the output of the unit test said *"Expected True, but got True"*, which took some minutes to figure out :p ... I think that's exactly what @SertacAkyuz was talking about.